# How to solve this type of recurrent relations using generation functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have no idea how to solve this relation, when $n$ in
$(n+2)^2\cdot g(n+2)+g(n)=0$ using generating functions, not induction (this exercise meets me in generating functions method paragraph I tried $z^n$ and $z^n\over n!$ but didn't succeed.

Comment: If $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(n)x^n,$ then $xG'(x)=\sum ng(n)x^n$ and thus $G'(x)+xG''(x)=\sum (n+1)^2g(n+1)x^n.$ Then  $$x G(x)+G'(x)+xG''(x)=g(1).$$ Don't know how to solve that differential equation.

Comment: ahh, i stuck at  differential equation stage too)